# Chart.js - scaleType='date' not working

Tags: chart.js, scaletype

Using Chart.js, I'm trying to get the x-axis (and toolips) to show a DATE, but all I can get are large integers appearing as the x-axis label.  I've compared what the example in the documentation does and I don't see what it's doing that i'm not.  Can anyone please help?

Here's the tiny example that I created showing it not working.
(btw - as a side issue, notice that if the color of the RED line is spelled Red rather than red, the line looks normal, but tooltips no longer work on that line)
https://plnkr.co/edit/CKUf4zFC1vhe3VNUF5Lf?p=preview

```
javascript for the above plunker example is below
----------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script>
      var chartData = {
        datasets: [{
          borderColor: 'Red',
          label: 'Capital R in borderColor, tooltips dont work',
          data: [{
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T11:45:00'),
            y: 25
          }, {
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T12:51:00'),
            y: 28
          }, {
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T14:10:00'),
            y: 22
          }, {
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T15:15:00'),
            y: 18
          }]
        }, {
          borderColor: 'green',
          label: 'borderColor all lower case, tooltips now work',
          data: [{
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T11:45:00'),
            y: 15
          }, {
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T12:51:00'),
            y: 18
          }, {
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T14:10:00'),
            y: 12
          }, {
            x: new Date('2011-04-11T15:15:00'),
            y: 8
          }]
        }, ]
      };


      window.onload = function() {

        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myScatterxx = Chart.Scatter(ctx, {
          data: chartData,
          scaleType: 'date',
          options: { title: { display: true, text: "scaleType='date' isn't working", fontSize:36} },
        });
      };
    </script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since the documentation is messy, I'm not surprised you didn't get how to create a time-scale chart. The actual call is the following :

```js
window.myScatterxx = Chart.Scatter(ctx, {
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "it is now working",
            fontSize: 36
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                // This is the important part
                type: "time",
            }]
        }
    },
});
```

---

Now you have the correct syntax, you'd need to import the correct library as well. As I can see in the piece of code you gave, you imported `Chart.min.js`, but you need more since you know work with the time element.

You can either :

- Import [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ([*CDN link*](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js)) and then `Chart.min.js`.
- Import [`Chart.bundle.min.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.bundle.min.js), that contains both Moment and Chart libraries.

---

Finally, I also noticed in your code you had a problem displaying tooltips for the red dataset. It is because you defined its color as `Red`. Change it to `red` and tooltips will work again :

```js
datasets: [{
    borderColor: 'red',
    label: 'Capital R in borderColor, tooltips now work',
    data: [
        // ...
    ]
}]
```

---

You can see all these fixes live [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oe1r8kbw/), and here is the final result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Tekiv!

Comment: A follow-up question, that I hope is simple as well, is how can I customize the tooltip to show only the Date portion without the Time?  In my actual application, only Date is important.

btw - on the Red vs red.  I did realize that all lower case on the color makes the tooltips work. But, it's inconsistent in that the color 'Red' does make the color of the line red, but that it breaks the tooltip.  Seems like internally a comparison of colors with the addition of a .toLowerCase() call would make it more forgiving.

Again, much thanks!

Comment: @user2191367 A pleasure ! -- As for the tooltip edit, check the [documentation about tooltips callback](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration) (*scroll down a bit until "Tooltip Callbacks"*). Also check this [other fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oe1r8kbw/1/) with an idea on what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you again Tektiv!  That's exactly what I needed

Comment: @user2191367  Glad I helped !